# Access Denied Signed Cookies AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have been trying aws cloudfront sign package for a while, and i could get signedURL work to my cloudfront which means the cloudfront is setup properly. But there is an issue when i tried to use signed cookies in my cloudfront.

What could be the reasons for not working with signed cookies? And using postman to send cookies to the Cloudfront link for testing purpose.

Before passing the cookie values
[image]

After passing cookie values

[image]

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer, in the option parameters, we have to define the expiry time according to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFront/Signer.html).

Otherwise the default time will get expired in the [library](https://github.com/jasonsims/aws-cloudfront-sign) I used.

Comment: To summarize it should be unix utc timestamp example : 1556668800.

Answer (score 4):

Wildcards in the resource URLs of canned policies were not working for me. I had to use a custom policy for wildcards to work. In addition, make sure if you are signing the cookies for an HTTPS url you are testing your requests with an HTTPS url (obvious but easy to mess up)

Comment: That was exactly it for me! As soon as I specified https:// in the url to generate the cookie it worked!

Comment: Could you please help me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73556541/cloud-front-signed-cookie-resource-path

Answer (score 3):

Your signed cookies are working based on the information above. Looks like the resource you are trying to access does not exist or permission denied.

If you are accessing to S3 bucket, make sure it is set to public read. If you are accessing via API Gateway, make sure you can access those URL's without cloudfront.

Comment: I'm accessing via API Gateway. And it can be access without cloudfront.

Comment: In that case, the resource you are trying to access does not exist or does not have permissions. Enabling API Gateway detailed logs will give you some insight of what is going on.

Comment: Thank you will try

Answer (score 0):

I had totally the same error response. Turns out in the `CloudFront-Policy` cookie I was setting incorrect path to the Resource(s). I had no clue that its important for CloudFront to know the domain and even the protocol.

In my case I was setting policy Resource as relative path, which is **WRONG**! See below what I mean is wrong:

```
path_to_my_resources/*
```

Here's how your resource should look if you want to access it through the CloudFront domain that they generated for you:

```
http://somedomain.cloudfront.net/path_to_my_resources/*
```

or for HTTPS

```
https://somedomain.cloudfront.net/path_to_my_resources/*
```

Finally if you want to access it through your own domain (CNAME), then you should use it in the resource property:

```
https://example.com/path_to_my_resources/*
```

This is the final policy statement that worked for me:

```
{
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Resource":"https://example.com/path_to_my_resources/*",
         "Condition":{
            "IpAddress":{
               "AWS:SourceIp":"127.0.0.1/32"
            },
            "DateLessThan":{
               "AWS:EpochTime":1554469015
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

And here's the link where you can read more about Policy Statement for signed cookie that uses custom policy: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-setting-signed-cookie-custom-policy.html#private-content-custom-policy-statement-signed-cookies-examples